# lookup_friendships (rtweet package) works arbitrarily

Tags: r, api, rtweet

I'm trying to build a matrix showing whether each of 91 Twitter accounts follows all of the others, and I'm using the R function `lookup_friendships` from the `rtweet` package, whose authentication I've completed.

For example each of the 4095 calculations need a call to a function like this:

```
lookup_friendships("BillGates","realDonaldTrump")
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Is this related to the 15-minute rate limit? The function help doesn't mention any rate limit.

Comment: There are [rate limits for that endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits) of 180 requests per window (15 min).

Comment: I see, thank you. Then it's "faster" to use `get_friends` (7 hour quarters).